# Using one function to handle both POST/GET API calls with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

As the title says what I was trying to do is make a universal function to both do `GET` and `POST` calls with one function. However, because when sending a `GET` call it requires the `params` entry to contain the data, when sending data via `POST` it requires the `data` entry (if I'm not mistaken).

I currently have the following function;

```
function api(method, call, params){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    axios({
      url: call,
      method,
      params
    }).then(function(response) {
      var body = response.data;
      if(body.status !== 1){
        return reject(body.message);
      }

      resolve(body.response);
    }).catch(function(err){
      reject(err);
    });
  });
```

GET calls work fine as there is the params entry, but for POST calls it stops working. How can I fix this so I have one function to handle both calls?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just pulling the object into a variable and adding the entry.

Example:

```
var data = {
  url: call,
  method
}

if(method.toLowerCase() === 'post'){
  data['data'] = params;
}else{
  data['params'] = params;
}    

axios(data).then(function(response) ...
```

Comment: `data['params'] = data;` How would this work? You are assigning `data` to `data.param`?

Comment: Yea it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to accept `config` object as a parameter. Also, you do not need to wrap `axios()` in a new promise`as`axios()` returns a promise itsef.

```
function api(config) {
  const baseUrl = "http://foo.baz";

  const updatedConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    // If you want to append base url to all api methods.
    url: `${baseUrl}${config.url}`
  });

  return axios(updatedConfig).then(response => {
    const body = response.data;

    if (body.status !== 1) {
      throw new Error(body.message);
    }

    return body.response;
  });
}
```

**Usage:**

```
api({
  url: "/user",
  method: "get",
  params: { id: "xyz" }
}).then(() => { });
```

or

```
api({
  url: "/tag",
  method: "post",
  data: { tag: "abc" }
}).then(() => { });
```

Comment: What goes for returning a promise, I never knew I could just return within axios' response, is it bad in any way that I've done it the way I have up until this point (if not, I will just keep it like I have done for the project as I've used multiple things like this, and I like my code to be continuous)

Comment: There is no harm in using it but it's unnecessary.